# How can I convert from underscores to camel case with a regex?

Tags: regex, pcre, camelcasing, case-conversion

How can I convert names with underscores into camel case names as follows using a **single** Java/Perl regular expression search and replace?

```
underscore_variable_name -> underscoreVariableName
UNDERSCORE_VARIABLE_NAME -> underscoreVariableName
_LEADING_UNDERSCORE -> leadingUnderscore
```

The reason I ask for a single regular expressions is that I want to do this using Eclipse or Notepad++ search and replace.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Some Perl examples](http://ideone.com/pf0Yk):

```
my $str = 'variable_name, VARIABLE_NAME, _var_x_short,  __variable__name___';

### solution 1
$_ = $str;

$_ = lc;
s/_(\w)/\U$1/g;

say;

### solution 2: multi/leading underscore fix
$_ = $str;

$_ = lc;
s/(?<=[^\W_])_+([^\W_])|_+/\U$1/g;

say;

### solution 3: without prior lc
$_ = $str;

s/(?<=[^\W_])_+([^\W_])|([^\W_]+)|_+/\U$1\L$2/g;

say;
```

Output:

```
variableName, variableName, VarXShort,  _variable_name__
variableName, variableName, varXShort,  variableName
variableName, variableName, varXShort,  variableName
```

Comment: +1: Neat.  About the only possible quibble is that `_tea_break` would become `TeaBreak` rather than `teaBreak` or `_teaBreak`.  But that would serve someone right for using names starting with an underscore.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you're right, and there would also be problems if multiple consecutive underscores were used. Updated the answer to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, but because this is for use in editor search and replace dialogs I was asking to do this using a single regex. `$_ = lc` breaks this constraint. Can you think of a way to combine them?

Comment: @glenviewjeff, the `lc` less solution didn't work right for names like `var_x_short`, updated and fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. You stand next to Jesus in my book.

Answer (score 5):

Uppercases letters following _-:

```
s/[_-]([a-z])/\u$1/gr
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have camelCase variables in the string, then @Qtax's answer will make them lowercase. If all of your variables are lower-case under_scored then you can make the following modification to #3: `W` --> `A-Z`

```
's/(?<=[^\A-Z_])_+([^\A-Z_])|([^\A-Z_]+)|_+/\U$1\L$2/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer user846969's answer but somehow it was not finding other matches in the tool that is using EBNF (extended Backus-Naur form). Here is somthing that worked for me:

```regex
/(?:([a-z0-9]*)[_-])([a-z])/${1}${2:/upcase}/g
```